# Test failures on executing mvn clean install

Tags: maven

Getting this error all the time, when I'm trying to run mvn clean install.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test
>   (default-test) on project openstack-neutron: There are test failures.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Will it be a problem, if I skip the tests?

Comment: I agree with @AleksandrM. nothing bad really happens if you skip tests, but all the idea of tests is to test your code, and to make sure they pass...

Comment: This is about goto, but it is the same for skipping tests - http://xkcd.com/292/.

Answer (score 1):

you can skip tests using

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

but I agree with Aleksandr - you should fix the tests :-) all the idea of tests is to test your code, and to make sure they pass...